# Converting HLists back to tuples as in Shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am trying to understand the internals of `shapeless` as an exercise.
Right now, I am confused with how method `tupled` of `HList`s works.

Example:

```scala
scala> val l = "er" :: 3 :: HNil
l: shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil]] = er :: 3 :: HNil
```

```scala
scala> l.tupled
res0: (String, Int) = (er,3)
```

What helps me go through the code is to write my own minimal version of the classes I wish to understand. Here it is for `HList`:

```scala
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed trait HList

final class HNil extends HList {
def ::[T](v : T) = HCons(v, this)
}

val HNil = new HNil()

final case class HCons[H, T <: HList](head : H, tail : T) extends HList {
def ::[T](v : T) = HCons(v, this)
}

type ::[H, T <: HList] = HCons[H, T]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait HList
defined class HNil
HNil: HNil = HNil@7f32618c
defined class HCons
defined type alias $colon$colon
```

What is the minimum amount of code that needs to be added to this to implement a working `tupled` method?
I fear there is no small amount...

Comment: The code for `tupled` is actually generated boilerplate (`hlistTupler1` … `hlistTupler22` for each product size supported by Scala): https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/project/Boilerplate.scala#L130

Comment: @devkat This is a valid answer